# How do I add existing library files into TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

I am new to TFS and I'm trying to add some custom library files that the whole team uses into Team explorer in Visual Studio. It's library files of Sahi Testing tool so that any changes made to the files can be seen on all machines. I have tried searching online but could not find exactly what I want. Help

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have the following options:

- If you have Nuget Packages for the libraries, you do not necessarily have to add the packages to source control and restore them when you need them. See this [link](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control) for details.
- As an alternative, you can add libraries as binary files to source control so that each developer or build server can retrieve them together with the source code. It's a good practice, to add them to a special location so that they are located in one place and not spread over the solution. However, only use this approach for binaries that do not change too often. Otherwise, you might bloat your TFS database if the files are large and change very often.